# Delete Customers from DV360 FirstAndThirdPartyAudience

Tags: google-api, dv360

We want to automatically fully update a FirstAndThirdPartyAudience in Google Display & Video 360 via the API. We are using the REST API (https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v3/firstAndThirdPartyAudiences) to create a new audience and add or update customers of an already existing audience. But there is currently no method to clear the list of all customers in the audience. When using the web UI then I think it is possible either delete the audience completely or recreate the customer list.

Is there are way to update an already existing audience fully? Would it work to set the membershipDurationDays to a low value and continuously renewing the customers in the audience to keep the list up-to-date?